# Create chart series, add data and set visibility

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I'm trying to create a group of chart series, add data to the series and then show a few of the series by making them visible. The data changes and a user can select which series to view. I think this method will be better than clearing all series with `chart.Series.Clear();` and then recreating the series in the same method.

For example a list of cars in a carpool with random mileages and then select which cars to show.

The code below doesn't work (I've commented where). The series aren't public and I think they need to be added to a public collection like a `SeriesCollection` but I'm not sure how.

Thanks for any help.

```
// create new chart series and add to a chartarea
        ChartArea TestChartArea = new ChartArea();
        public void CreateChartSeries()
        {
            List<string> lstCars = new List<string> { "Mazda", "Tesla", "Honda", "Jaguar", "Ford", "Toyota" };

            foreach (string Car in lstCars)
            {
                // car series created correctly?
                var Srs = new Series(Car); 
                Srs.ChartArea = TestChart.Name;
                Srs.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                Srs.Color = Color.Red;
                Srs.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
                TestChart.Series.Add(Srs);
            }
        }

        // add data to chart series
        public void SeriesData()
        {
            List<string> lstCars = new List<string> { "Mazda", "Tesla", "Honda", "Jaguar", "Ford", "Toyota" };
            int[] Xseries = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
            int[] Milage = new int[10];

            Random Random = new Random();

            foreach (string Car in lstCars)
            {
                for (int M = 0; M < 10; M++)
                    Milage[M] = Random.Next(150, 15000);

                // not sure how to call and add data to each series
                Srs.Points.DataBindXY(Xseries, Milage);  
            }
        }

        // plot series - some visible
        public void PlotCreatedSeries()
        {
            // not sure how to refer to each series
            Mazda.Enabled = true;  
            Tesla.Enabled = false;
            Honda.Enabled = true;
            Jaguar.Enabled = false;
            Ford.Enabled = true;
            Toyota.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name `'Srs'` you use to create the `Series` is only in scope i.e. usable within the loop. At the end of the loop you do add the newly created `Series` to your `Chart`:

```
 TestChart.Series.Add(Srs);
```

The `Series` **property** **is** a public `SeriesCollection`. This is a bit confusing, as the **singular type** name and the **plural property** name are the same in this case, as oppose to, say, `Legend(s)` or `ChartArea(s)`..

From now on you can access it either by its index..

```
 Series s = TestChart.Series[0]  // the series you have added first
```

..or, more readable and more stable, by its `Name` property:

```
 Series s = TestChart.Series["Mazda"]   // the same series

 TestChart.Series["Mazda"].Enabled = true;
```

Note that *'name'* is also a tricky word:

When you declare a variable you give it a 'name'. `Series s = new Series();`

But many objects also have a **property** called `Name`: `s.Name = "Volvo";`

The former must be unique but the latter is just a string; do keep it unique as well, but the system will not guard you.

The former can never change, but, as you have seen, can go out of scope; the latter is just a string and you can change it.

Note that the variable itself doesn't go out of scop as long as it is still referenced somewhere, here as an element of the `SeriesiesCollection Series`..

Whether you want to add `DataPoints` bound **or** directly is up to you.

For the former there are [many binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456766.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) options.

For the latter you can use the [`Chart.Points` methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.datapointcollection_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)..:

- `Add(DataPoint)`
- `AddY(YValue)`
- `AddXY(XValues, YValue(s))`

Note that sometimes, especially with live charts it makes sense to **insert** a `DataPoint` using one of the `InsertXXX` methods!

Do look it up in MSDN! The middle version makes only sense if the x-values are either non-numeric or have to no real meaning, like, say, names.. - Note that adding meaningful x-values as **numbers** (or `DateTimes`) is crucial to use them for further goals, like tooltips, zoom or display ranges etc..

Failing to do so is probably the most common mistake newbies make. The `Chart` **looks ok**, but the data inside are broken, read lost.